# How to make count down timer in Java?

Tags: java, timer, label

I want count down every second and update the label text?

```
int countdown = 100;

public void countingDown() {
    countdown = countdown - 1;
    label.setText(countdown + "second's left");
}
```

so how to run `countingDown` every second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maybe do like this:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyTimer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new App(), 0, 1000);
    }
}

class App extends TimerTask {

    int countdown = 100;

    public void run() {
        countdown = countdown - 1;
        System.out.println(countdown);
        //label.setText(countdown +"second's left");
    }

}

// Result:
//99
//98
//97
//96
//95
//94
```

It just works. Change `System.out.println(countdown);` by `label.setText(countdown +"second's left");` as what you want.

Reference
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/TimerTask.html 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Timer.html

Comment: `timer.schedule(new App(), 0, 1000);` 1000 is stop time (= 1 second). If you want 2.5 seconds, change it to `timer.schedule(new App(), 0, 2500);`

Comment: If i want to stop the timer when it countdown reach 0

Comment: You add condition inside method: `public void run() { if(countdown != 0){ countdown = countdown - 1; System.out.println(countdown); } }`

Answer (score 1):

control variable or you can set your on time(seconds)

```
int counter = 40;
 
    while(counter>0){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(counter);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        counter--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        final Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //countingDown stuff;
            }
        };
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(refresh, 0, 1,SECONDS);
```

Comment: it showing me error                                 scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(refresh, 0, 1,SECONDS);

Comment: It should be `scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(refresh, 0, 1,Timer.SECONDS);`

Comment: Please do  import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run on android use this

```
int Seconds = 11;
    void Start() {
        Seconds--;
        Log.i(TAG, "Start: "+ Seconds);;
        if(Seconds !=0){
            new Handler().postDelayed(this::Start, 1000);
        }
    }
```

it will work without affecting GUI

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
int countdown=100;

    public void countingDown(){

     new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
             countdown=countdown - 1;

                label.setText(countdown +"second's left");
            }   
        },0, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Call countingDown() once, it's working on my machine

Comment: i have edited the code. placed countdown=countdown - 1; in run() method. and place System.out.println(); in run method to test.Can you please try and let me know